# Slider with stop points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to create a slider which has some stop points. Whenever I click on any item, I want the slider to jump at that point and do some action. I have created the slider with jQuery UI's slider. It's pretty easy, but I don't exactly know how to add those stop points. Is there a ready-made library for this or should I implement this myself? If so, could you please help me get on track?

[image: Slider with stop points]

Comment: `click on any item`... what items? Could put `data` attribute on those items and set slider from that value. Need more detail about what you need exactly. A demo in jsfiddle.net would help, with enough data to work with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did something similar to this before. It's basically working like this:

- I store all possible values in an array (in my case "*keyframes*" like your "*stop points*")
- the `stop()`-callback of the slider triggers a function called `_getClosest` and sets the new value
- a click on the links below the slider let the it jump directly to that position

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/eTTM2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="keyframes">
    <a>|</a><a>|</a><a>|</a><a>|</a><a>|</a><a>|</a><a>|</a>
</div>
```

**Slider, links and keyframes**

```
var slider = $('slider');
var links = $('#keyframes > a');
var values = [0, 10, 34, 67, 80, 85, 100];

// initiate slider
slider.slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    animate: 500,
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        slider.slider('value', _getClosest(ui.value) );
    }
});

// add click to the links
links.click(function() {
    slider.slider('value', values[$(this).index()]);
});
```

**How to get the closest element to slide to**

The easiest way is to compare the current slider position to the possible keyframes:

- if I'm already half the way or further I move to the next element
- if I've not reached the middle, I go back to the element before

So `_getClosest()` can look like this:

```
function _getClosest(value) {
    var closest = null;
    $.each(values, function(_key, _value) {
        if (closest == null || Math.abs(this-value) < Math.abs(closest-value)) {
            closest = this;
        }   
    });
    return closest;
}
```

**Place links below the slider corresponding to their values**

To place the links at their respective position, simply loop thru them and set the left offset according to the values from the `values`-array. This time I multiplied the value with a factor of `2` because the slider in the demo is `200px` wide but has a range from `0-100`:

```
$.each(links, function(key, value) {
    $(value).css('left', values[key] * 2);
});
```

Comment: First of all, this is beautiful. Thanks. But, I want the user to be able to access all points (0-100 in this case) and also highlight some stop points for him. The user can slide the slider freely but if he/she wants to move to that specific point he/she can click on the orange points underneath.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori I've updated my answer with a new demo and more explanation that should suite your case. Simply take off everything that is not needed to answer your question. :)