# Range slider should only stop at given positions

Tags: rangeslider

In the slider user can slide only at the provided position. 
Here are the details that i have for create the slider:

When user try to slide it should stop at below positions only.
0, 100, 300, 450, 650, 950

```
$("#range-slider").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  step: 1,
  slide: (event, ui) => {
  },
});
```

Can anyone have any idea how can we achieve this?

Comment: You might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191221/slider-with-stop-points

Comment: Yes it's working for me...I changed this according to my requirement and it's working for me. But with this we are not able to use keyboard arrow key(forward & backward) .